# How to display icon on the right side of menu items?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jmenuitem

In my project I want to display icons on the right side of `JMenuItem` entries. Below is my code, but it displays icon on the left side of menu items.

```
Icon student2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/new-student.png"));
JMenuItem student = new JMenuItem("New students",student1);
```

Comment: *"How to display icon on the right side of menu items?"*  Why (do that)?

Answer (score 1):

> i want to display icons on the right side of jemnu items

Try:

```
JMenuItem student = new JMenuItem(...);
student.setComponentOrientation(JComponent.ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```